# New to PHP, what's wrong with my SQL query?

Tags: database, string, postgresql

I'm trying to execute a query using PHP via its PostgreSQL-specific built-in functions, however I can't figure out why my queries aren't being run. Could someone please point me in the right direction regarding what could be wrong with the following code:

```
//create our final insert statement as a string
$final_insert_query = $beginningOfInsertStmt . $oneRowFormatted . ");";
    echo $final_insert_query; // the output of this is listed below
    // run the query and store result in $result           
    $result = pg_query($dbconn, $final_insert_query);
    if (!$result) {
       echo "An error occurred!!!!.";
       exit;
    }
    else{
    echo $result . " was SUCCESSFUL!";
    }
```

The output of this script is currently:

```
INSERT INTO POP_HOUSING_ESTIMATE_STATE VALUES(1, 'South', 'East South Central',
'Alabama', 4784762, 4803689, 2173898, 2182088);

An error occurred!!!!.
```

Thus, the `$final_insert_query` variable should contain the following string (which appears to be a valid SQL INSERT statement by all means):

```
INSERT INTO POP_HOUSING_ESTIMATE_STATE VALUES(1, 'South', 'East South Central',
'Alabama', 4784762, 4803689, 2173898, 2182088);
```

I should also mention that I have successfully inserted the same exact line via the terminal directly into my PosgreSQL database. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Add [This](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to your code, and see what error you are actually getting.  That will give you an idea of where to turn.

Comment: You can add pg_last_error() to see what wrong happened

Comment: Verify that your $dbconn is properly initialized.

Comment: you should make your title clearer - a few words about your issue, not generic "problem"

Answer (score 2):

There are several things wrong here:

- Your code is probably vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  See [PHP manual on SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and this site. Please use parameterised queries ("prepared statements").
- You aren't getting the full error so it's going to be very hard for you to diagnose the fault. As per [the manual for `pg_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php) you can use [`pg_last_error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-last-error.php) to get the error details.

I suspect the immediate problem is likely to be case sensitivity; you probably created your table as `"POP_HOUSING_ESTIMATE_STATE"` but you're querying it as `POP_HOUSING_ESTIMATE_STATE`. Note the different quoting. See [Identifiers and keywords](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in the PostgreSQL manual for a description of PostgreSQL's *case folding* behaviour. Such case folding is required by ANSI SQL, though PostgreSQL folds to lower case instead of the standard-specififed upper-case.

Comment: In addition to Craig's note, I would add that since you aren't specifying columns, it is possible you are not inserting data into the columns you think you are...  It's generally good practice to have a list of columns....

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to paste your SQL string directly into postgresql, then you can rule out your SQL syntax.  That leaves your connection.  Several things could go wrong here... no network path, bad password, typo in server name, neglected to run pg_connect(), etc.

`echo pg_last_error($dbconn)` immediately after you've run `$dbconn=pg_connect($conn)` (however you've named it in your code).